# Neo4j variable as property name

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to use a variable as a property name in neo4j

```
MATCH(e: Event {id: "123"})
MATCH(u: User {id: "456"})
MERGE (u)-[a:ACTION]->(e)
ON MATCH 
SET e[a.t] = e[a.t] - 1
```

This gives the error:

```
Invalid input '[': expected an identifier character, whitespace, '{', 'x/X', node labels, a property map, a relationship pattern, '.', '(', '=' or "+=" (line 5, column 6 (offset: 96))
"SET e[a.t] = e[a.t] - 1"
```

While according to this forum: it should be possible.
[Neo4j forum](https://community.neo4j.com/t5/about-the-community/can-i-use-variable-for-property-name-in-driver-cypher-query/ta-p/39084)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we want to create a relationship dynamically, and set its properties dynamically, we should use [`apoc.merge.relationship`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.merge/apoc.merge.relationship/) function. In this function you can dynamically provide `startNode`, `endNode`, properties to set `onMatch` and `onCreate` for the relationship and some other params as well.
For your use case, you can try something like this:

```
MATCH(e: Event {id: "123"})
MATCH(u: User {id: "456"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[rel:ACTION]->(e)
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(
  u, 
  "ACTION",
  {},
  {},
  e,
  apoc.map.setKey({}, toString(rel.t), rel.t - 1)
)
YIELD rel
RETURN rel;
```

Also, note that we have to fetch the relationship using `OPTIONAL MATCH` so that we can access its properties when calling the `apoc` function. Finally, you will also need to install `APOC` library for the above query to work.

Answer (score 1):

The example as you pointed out in the forum uses the node['property'] form in the WHERE clause. It does not work when updating the property like you did.
For example, below query works

```
match (n:Actor)  
where n['name'] = "Neo"  
set n.age = 50 
return n

Result:

n
(0:Actor {age:50, name:"Neo"})

Query took 14 ms and returned 1 rows. 
Updated the graph - set 1 property
```

BUT THIS WILL NOT WORK:

```
 set n['age'] = 50
```